# Activity cannot cast to listener

Tags: android, interface

In my project i have created an interface called `VerifiedListnerInterface` in which it contains method `public void VerifiedInterfaceListner(String VarifiedValue);` .Now i have an Activity that contains Navigation Drawer.
In that drawer i am opening fragment on `OnItemClickListner` and it works fine.

But when i try to assign a listner It gives me the class cast exception.

```
HomeActivity cannot be cast to com.Interfaces.VerifiedInterface
```

My code in itemClickListner is:

```
if(position==3)
{
VerifiedInterface listner = (VerifiedInterface) HomeActivity.this;
                    listner.VerifiedInterfaceListner(ConstantFunction.getStatus(HomeActivity.this, ConstantVariables.VERIFIED));
                    openNewFragment(new EditProfileFragment(), "driverEditProfile");
}
```

And my custom Interface class is

```
public interface VerifiedInterface {
    public void VerifiedInterfaceListner(String VarifiedValue);
}
```

So how to initialize a listner

My code for opening the fragment is

```
public void openNewFragment(Fragment f, String tag) {


        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

        if (fragment != null) {
            if (currentFragment != null) {
                if (fragment.getClass().equals(currentFragment.getClass())) {
                    driverNavigationdrawer.closeDrawers();
                    return;
                }
            }
            ft.show(fragment);
            ft.hide(currentFragment);
            currentFragment = fragment;

        } else {
            if (currentFragment != null)
                ft.hide(currentFragment);

            ft.add(R.id.driverFrameContainer, f, tag);
            currentFragment = f;
        }
        ft.commit();
        driverNavigationdrawer.closeDrawers();
    }
```

Comment: you can just use 
`VerifiedInterface listner = HomeActivity.this;`
And if your activity is implementing that interface you should get no errors

Comment: No My activity is not implementing interface..because i want to implement somewhere else..i just want to get the value in listner

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Like every answer mentioned here, you need to implement interface in HomeActivity. If you want it  in some other activity, typecast with that activity. Or if you need something else edit you question and mention where you actually want this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error it looks like your HomeActivity is not an instance of type VerifiedInterface.

Make sure that you're actually implementing the interface in your HomeActivity, ex:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VerifiedInterface {
   //rest of the code of HomeActivity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your HomeActivity implement VerifiedInterface? Like so:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VerifiedListenerInterface {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No,I want to inpliment the listner somewhere else..I just want to assign a value here

Comment: Ok, but you get cast problem because HomeActivity doesn't implement this interface.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to pass your activity in the Constructor of the other class

in your activity which implements the interface:

```
otherClass obj = otherClass(HomeActivity.this);
```

And in your otherClass.java :

Create an reference anywhere :

```
VerifiedInterface listener
```

Write a Constructor :

```
otherClass(VerifiedInterface listenerpassed){
    this.listener = listenerpassed;
}
```

So now here in otherClass you can use this `listener` to send a callback to the activity :

```
listener.VerifiedInterfaceListner(VarifiedValue);
```

And in your `HomeActivity`you will get call back in `VerifiedInterfaceListner`

```
@Override
public void VerifiedInterfaceListner(String VarifiedValue){
//Do your stuff like opening another fragment ..
}
```

Comment: but i want to assign a value to the listner which will reflect where i have implemented that interface..How can i do that

Comment: but the widget i want to access is in fragment how could i access widget in HomeActivity? and also i am using only one instance of that fragment

Comment: in your fragment when your widget is pressed or when your work is done use `listener.VerifiedInterfaceListner(VarifiedValue);` to pass the String value to the HomeActivity and then that String is now available in your HomeActivity to be used !!

Comment: See my question is simple whenever i click on Drawer Menu i want to assign a value to the interface.On that click i don't want to reload the fragment,I just want the value there in my fragment in the method that i implemented in that listner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139137/discussion-between-abhaybohra-and-shadygoneinsane).